# Getting only last element from the list [Kotlin]

Tags: android, list, kotlin, mutablelist

This problem is in reference to Android :
I have a function which takes in a string value and I want to print a list of Integers from 0 upto that number. I am able to get the string inside the loop but outside the loop I am only getting the last element.

What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

My code :

```
private fun floorsListFromReceived(floors: String): MutableList<Int> {

        var floorList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
        var count = 0
        while( count <= floors.toInt()) {
            floorList = mutableListOf(count)
            count++
            Timber.d("List of Floors Inside is : $floorList")
        }
        Timber.d("List of Floors Outside  is : $floorList")
        return floorList
    }
```

LOG :
[image]

Comment: Hi. You're reassigning floorList here: `floorList = mutableListOf(count)`. Did you mean to add count to the existing floorList instance? BR

Comment: Yes I am trying to make a list so therefore `floorList = mutableListOf(count)` so after every loop `count` gets added to the list.

Comment: You're creating a new list with one item in it every time - basically throwing the old list out. If you want a single list, then you should only be creating one once (e.g. `mutableListOf()`) and then *adding* stuff to it. The fact you're creating new lists in your loop when you only want one is a warning sign!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yes I am trying to make a list so therefore floorList =
> mutableListOf(count) so after every loop count gets added to the list.

Then you should do like this:

```
while (count <= floors.toInt()) {
    floorList.add(count)
    count++
    Timber.d("List of Floors Inside is : $floorList")
}
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!! Can I get the explanation? Seems like I was doing wrong initializing the `floorList` variable again.

Comment: Good to hear! You were reassigning the floorList in the loop, hence the previous instance got lost in space, and you ended up with the last instance after the loop. I hope this makes sense. BR

Comment: Yeah makes sense, that's why in the logs it was showing 5 statements and every time there was just one element in the list instead of one single list of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating the list every time you go through the while loop `floorList = mutableListOf(count)`.
You need to just use the mutableList you already created before, `floorList` and add your values to it using the `add` function.

Also, you can use a for loop instead of a while loop for better readability.

```
var floorList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
for (count in 0 .. floors.toInt()){
    floorList.add(count)
}
```

Or an even easier aproach with a list comprehension like aproach like this.

```
val floorsList =(0 .. floors).toList()
```

or this

```
val floorsList = List(floors.toInt()) { it }
```

Comment: `val floorsList = List(floors.toInt()) { it + 1 }`
-> this will create a list from 1 to the given number, whereas the author needed the list to start from 0.

Comment: You're right, missed that, but i just wanted to mainly mention it as an alternative for the author to know.